# Linux - Require error

Tags: node.js

i'm working in a thing in Nodejs.
This give me a error... but i can't find the answer..

```
 var Main = Electron.remote.require('main.js');
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined
at Object. (/opt/lampp/htdocs/Bot_Farm/farmer.js:11:27)
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:575:3
root@vps21:/opt/lampp/htdocs/Bot_Fa# node farmer.js
module.js:487
throw err;
^
```

Hope u can help me fast.

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'require' of undefined

Means that node is unable to identify `remote`, which might be because Electron is not required.

Have you required Electron?
I guess the solution to your problem is:

```
var Electron = require('electron')
```

Answer (score 0):

js is a file you created. Basically Electron.remote is undefined / null.

If you wish to require your main.js file you may use

```
Var x = require("main.js");
```

Alternatively you can debug why Electron.remote is not instantiated however the reference documentation I have found here:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md

I hope this points you in the right direction

You may also try

```
var electron = require("electron").remote;
```

Comment: Thanks for the context - your first post omitted the crucial step of defining Electron. Best of luck sir!

Answer (score 0):

My code is like that.

```
var SteamUser = require('steam-user');
var Steam = SteamUser.Steam;
var request = require('request');
var Cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require("fs");

var client = new SteamUser({"enablePicsCache": 
true,"promptSteamGuardCode":false});

var Electron = require('electron');
var Main = Electron.remote.require('main.js');

var g_Jar = request.jar();
request = request.defaults({"jar": g_Jar});
```